# garbage disposal still works but the sink just does not drain

Tags: sink, kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

The garbage disposal under the kitchen sink still runs, but the sink just does not drain. What can the reason, do I have to open the garbage disposal? Are there any easy ways to fix?

Comment: Is it a 2-sided kitchen sink, and if so are both sides backed up? Are there any other drain problems? Have there *been* any other drain problems recently?

Comment: If the trap is clogged, you may be able to plunge it from the top. Block the other sink with a rag if there are two. Dishwasher? You may force the waste water into the dishwasher, check inside when you are done. A picture may help.

Answer (score 1):

In my last house, any time my wife would put large amounts of lettuce or cabbage leaves or similar vegetables through the disposal the discharge drain after the disposal would plug up causing me to have to take the drain apart and remove the plugging. Using a plunger just made the plugging worse since it would only compact the stuff in the discharge piping.

Comment: I had that happen a few weeks ago. The trap was clogged with egg shells when my wife was making deviled eggs for Christmas. I took the trap into the yard and knocked everything out of it.